# Oracle Subquery (trazer os 6 menores)

Tags: oracle

Oi alguém pode me dar uma ajuda? tenho a estrutura abaixo, ela retorna 4 colunas, preciso que fique com 6, mas me perdi nos "batida <>"

```
SELECT DATA,
       NVL(
             (SELECT MIN(MINTOTIME(BATIDA,':'))
              FROM ABATFUN B
              WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                AND A.DATA=B.DATA),'00:00') ENTR1,
       NVL(
             (SELECT MIN(MINTOTIME(BATIDA,':'))
              FROM ABATFUN B
              WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                AND A.DATA=B.DATA
                AND BATIDA <>
                  (SELECT MIN(BATIDA)
                   FROM ABATFUN B
                   WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                     AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                     AND A.DATA=B.DATA)),'00:00') SAIDA1 ,
       NVL(
             (SELECT MIN(MINTOTIME(BATIDA,':'))
              FROM ABATFUN B
              WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                AND A.DATA=B.DATA
                AND BATIDA <>
                  (SELECT MIN(BATIDA)
                   FROM ABATFUN B
                   WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                     AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                     AND A.DATA=B.DATA)
                AND BATIDA <>
                  (SELECT MIN(BATIDA)
                   FROM ABATFUN B
                   WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                     AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                     AND A.DATA=B.DATA
                     AND BATIDA <>
                       (SELECT MIN(BATIDA)
                        FROM ABATFUN B
                        WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                          AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                          AND A.DATA=B.DATA))),'00:00') ENTRADA2 ,
       NVL(
             (SELECT MIN(MINTOTIME(BATIDA,':'))
              FROM ABATFUN B
              WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                AND A.DATA=B.DATA
                AND BATIDA <>
                  (SELECT MIN(BATIDA)
                   FROM ABATFUN B
                   WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                     AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                     AND A.DATA=B.DATA)
                AND BATIDA <>
                  (SELECT MIN(BATIDA)
                   FROM ABATFUN B
                   WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                     AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                     AND A.DATA=B.DATA
                     AND BATIDA <>
                       (SELECT MIN(BATIDA)
                        FROM ABATFUN B
                        WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                          AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                          AND A.DATA=B.DATA))
                AND BATIDA <>
                  (SELECT MIN(BATIDA)
                   FROM ABATFUN B
                   WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                     AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                     AND A.DATA=B.DATA
                     AND BATIDA <>
                       (SELECT MIN(BATIDA)
                        FROM ABATFUN B
                        WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                          AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                          AND A.DATA=B.DATA)
                     AND BATIDA <>
                       (SELECT MIN(BATIDA)
                        FROM ABATFUN B
                        WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                          AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                          AND A.DATA=B.DATA
                          AND BATIDA <>
                            (SELECT MIN(BATIDA)
                             FROM ABATFUN B
                             WHERE A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA
                               AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA
                               AND A.DATA=B.DATA)))),'00:00') SAIDA2
FROM AAFHTFUN A
WHERE CHAPA = '060637'
  AND CODCOLIGADA = '1'
  AND DATA >= '21/01/2016'
  AND DATA <= '20/02/2016'
```

--Não posso usar `ROWNUM` devido já estar em uma subquery não tenho como amarrar a subquery da rownum com a 1ª tabela

Comment: dá para fazer algo assim

Comment: dá para fazer algo assim na subquery .... (select valor from (select valor from tabela order by 1) where rownum < 6)      ou    tentar usar analytic function http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-may/o33sql-1917326.html

Comment: O problema é que a minha linha ja é uma subquery onde tenho que amarrar as tabelas A com B, no seu exemplo ela ficaria ali onde esta escrito tabela, só que quando coloca ali da erro não reconhecendo o A.Tabela ......que no caso A.CODCOLIGADA=B.CODCOLIGADA AND A.CHAPA=B.CHAPA AND A.DATA=B.DATA (nada que esta com A é reconhecido), por isso comentei Query, ((SubQuery),SubQuery da Subquery) (que a Query não da para amarrar com a Sub da Sub)

Comment: Faça assim @Samuel , esqueça o sql , publique a estrutura das tabelas exemplos de dados e o resultado esperado.